# Copying a Google Sheet and the existing script to a new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I am currently copying into a new file.  I was wondering if it is possible to also copy the the Google Script that is associated with the sheet.  Basically I have a button that activates some script and I would like that button and associated script to be copied over as well.  Currently the button copies but when hitting it, it says the ScriptFunction could not be found.  Does anyone have any ideas or know if this is possible?

Comment: When I make copies of spreadsheets I always get all of the contained scripts with it.  You will have to authorize the script in every copy though.

Comment: If the behaviour is different for Cooper, this question either needs more details on how to reproduce the problem, or perhaps it should be close as not reproducible.